# Angular2 program is not running , may be having issue with lite-server?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, typescript1.8

First time i am using Angular2 with typeScript . My Angular2 program is not running, showing following error while run using **npm start.**

```js
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start D:\Users\Abhay\Angular2_Demo\angularRouting
> concurrent "npm run lite"

[0]
[0] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite D:\Users\Abhay\Angular2_Demo\angularRouting
[0] > lite-server
[0]
[0] ** browser-sync config **
[0] { injectChanges: false,
[0]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[0]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[0]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[0] [BS] Access URLs:
[0]  -------------------------------------
[0]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[0]     External: http://202.54.6.180:3000
[0]  -------------------------------------
[0]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[0]  UI External: http://202.54.6.180:3001
[0]  -------------------------------------
[0] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[0] [BS] Watching files...
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /index.html
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 404 GET /node_module/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js>
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /app/boot.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 404 GET /node_module/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js>
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 404 GET /angular2/router
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /app/app.component.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 404 GET /angular2/router
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /app/courses.component.js
[0] 16.08.26 15:57:46 304 GET /app/course.service.js
```

here is my **

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <script src="node_module/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js>"></script>

    

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

**
If need any other file so please know me, and please give me some solutions.

Comment: It seems like you are using older angular version, please use the latest version, go through [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: I used  "npm install -g angular-cli" this command for update Angular but having same error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of angular you are using is out of date by quite a bit. You'll need to upgrade angular-cli to the latest version to start with and try again. From the docs, this is how to upgrade angular-cli:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

this should update angular-cli to the newest version and assure that you are using an up to date version of the framework too.